# Enabling and Disabling Radio Buttons with js

Tags: javascript, html

help! I am making a some of radio buttons to insert into my data base but with the selected value rules may not be selected twice, I have got the js code for but it doesn't work optimally,the problem is if I chosen 1 in price, then I chose 2 in distace then disable follows the second column while disable in the first column disappears.`

````
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').click(function() {

       $('input:radio').removeAttr('disabled');
       if($(this).is(':checked')) {
           var val = $(this).val();

           $('input:radio').each(function() {
               if(val == $(this).val()) {
                   $(this).attr('disabled',true);
               }
           });

           $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
       }
    });
});
</script>
<body>

  <form class="" action="" method="post">


  <table class="table borderless">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="1"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="2"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="3"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="4"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="5"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>distance</th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="1"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="2"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="3"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="4"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="5"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>facilities</th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="1"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="2"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="3"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="4"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="5"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>large</th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="1"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="2"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="3"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="4"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="5"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="sumbit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>```
[enter image description here][1]`


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QI93.png
````

Comment: So I understand, you'd like a radio group to be permanently disabled once a value is been selected for that group?

Comment: I would suggest to give a little bit more detail within your questions in the future as to what you would want your code to do functionality wise besides something very vague such as just disable the radio buttons. If I knew that you wanted the user to re-select previous values after clicking a radio button the first time, then I would've coded for it within my jsfiddle. Just a suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? 
https://jsfiddle.net/4ayLkm6h/1/

What I've done is create a variable to keep track of what the previous value was:

```
  const values = {};
```

I use this in the click handler to check "has the value changed for this column?", if it has, is re-enable all the checkboxes for that column(for example value=1):

```
  if (values[name]) {
    $('input:radio[value="' + values[name] + '"]').attr('disabled', false);
  }
```

Then I update the values for next time:

```
  values[name] = val;
```

Lastly I disable the ones in the current column:

```
$('input:radio[value="' + val + '"]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
```

The first time you click the check:

```
if (values[name]) {
```

Will be false, so I don't re-enable anything (because nothing is disabled yet), so this code is only relevant on the second click, to check if we need to re-enable the previous column before we disable the currently clicked column.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').click(function(){
        var btnGroup = "input:radio[value='" + $(this).attr('value') + "']";
    var btnNameGroup = "input:radio[name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']";
        $(btnGroup).attr('disabled',true);
    $(btnNameGroup).attr('disabled',true);
    });
});
```

This groups each radio with their corresponding names and values and you can only select one each within each row and each column. While doing so, the disabled attribute does not leave the groups after another radio button is selected. Since you did not state if you wanted to enable the radio button row again after the first click, I left them all disabled after the user selects something the first time. At least that's how I understood your question.

Here's the jsfiddle of what I've described, maybe this is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/x1c6mpgL/

Answer (score 0):

Here is something short and "cryptic", using ES6 function syntax.

First I create an array `rbv` with similar-value-options from all radio button names. This array contains then 5 jquery objects, each one of length=4.

In the click-handler of the radio buttons I then loop through this array and check for the number of checked elements in each column `rv.filter(':checked').length`. If it is `>0` I set the 'disable' attribute for this whole column to `true`, otherwise to `false`.

```js
$(function(){
 var rb =$('input:radio'),              // jquery object with all radio buttons
     rbv=$.makeArray($('[name=price]')) // array of jquery objects, one for each column
          .map(p=>rb.filter((i,r)=>r.value===p.value));
// click-event: check each column for number of checked elements and act accordingly
 rb.click(()=>rbv.forEach(rv=>rv.attr('disabled',rv.filter(':checked').length>0)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="" action="" method="post">


  <table class="table borderless">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="1"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="2"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="3"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="4"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="price"  value="5"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>distance</th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="1"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="2"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="3"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="4"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="distance"  value="5"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>facilities</th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="1"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="2"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="3"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="4"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="facilities"  value="5"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>large</th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="1"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="2"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="3"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="4"></th>
      <th><input type="radio" name="large"  value="5"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="sumbit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```